# Drop Down Menu Not Displaying with Overflow Visible

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm confused as to why my sub menu isn't displaying outside of it's container when overflow is set to visible...

http://foc.devrap.co.uk/

If anyone could point out the obvious, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#mainMenu {
margin:50px 0 0;
overflow:visible;
}

#nav_menu-6 {
float:left;
overflow:visible;
height:100px;
}

#nav_menu-7 {
float:right;
}

#mainMenu ul {
list-style-type:none;
}

#mainMenu ul > li {
float:left;
position:relative;
}

#mainMenu ul > li {
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
line-height:14px;
font-weight:400;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#676868;
position:relative;
}

#mainMenu ul > li:hover {
color:#fff;
background-color:#004a98;
}

#mainMenu ul > li a {
display:block;
padding:10px 15px;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
line-height:14px;
font-weight:400;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#676868;
}

#mainMenu ul > li a:hover {
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}

#mainMenu ul li ul.sub-menu {
position:absolute;
z-index:99999;
top:34px; left:0;
}
```

Comment: Wow...that's a whole lot of `!important` statements...that's a sign of a bigger problem.

Comment: OK, I've removed the important statements. It's a bad habit of mine when things aren't working as expected, to try and rule out Wordpress style conflicts.

Comment: I've added 100px height to the container, so that at least some of the menu is visible and as far as I'm aware, this confirms that I've added overflow visible to the correct container.

Comment: Doh! Just noticed the issue... Scroll-able header!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a fixed height on my container, which I'd set overflow to visible.